# The Eclectic Trio

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

> Angels lose their choppered slip
>   So as I do my ten marches
>   Let's eat from the maple jar

From the above information, your task is to work out *all* of the following:

- Who?
- Where?
- What?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Who, Where and What?

> Each line has two anagrams: a city (where) and a local band (who/what)

First line

> Los Angeles (Angels lose) / Red Hot Chili Peppers (their choppers slip)

Second line

> Oasis (So as I) / do my / Manchester (ten marches)

Third line

> Seattle (Let's eat) / from the / Pearl Jam (maple jar)

The title: Eclectic Trio

> stands for the three bands.